# To make the drawn text clear

Tags: android, paint

I have written the code to draw text on the image and to save the image,But the text which I am drawing is looking blur on the image.What modifications need to do to make it clear,Or if there is any other way to draw text on image in android

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(photo);
                Typeface tf = Typeface.create(topaste, Typeface.BOLD);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
                paint.setTypeface(tf);
                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

                paint.setStrokeWidth(12); 
                canvas.drawBitmap(photo, 0, 0, paint);
                canvas.drawText(topaste, 15, 120, paint);
                image.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You try like this

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            mPath.reset();
            mView.invalidate();
        }
```

here is example draw free hand and clear paint http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2012/10/free-hand-graw.html